# jQuery resize() not working accurate

Tags: jquery, html, resize

I'm using `.resize()` to recalculate some `<div>`s and elements for a responsive landing-page. But it seems that it's not working accurate because when I am resizing the window very fast, every element is not correctly positioned. If I'm resizing slow and calm, then everything is fine. It seems that `.resize()` is not firing "fast" enough that some calculations are missed.

My Code has nothing special:

```
var faktor = 1014/515;
$(window).resize(function() {   

    if($(window).width() <= 1015 && $(window).width() >= 800) { 
        var w = $(window).width();
        var h = w/faktor;

        $('#modul').css({'width': w, 'height': h});
        $('#footer').css('width', w);
        $('#headerlinks').css('width', $(window).width()-507);

    }

    if($(window).width() <= 801) {

    }
});
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try to throttle it a little using a timeout, see if it's better or worst:

```
(function () {
    var timeoutResize;
    $(window).resize(function () {
        clearTimeout(timeoutResize);
        timeoutResize = setTimeout(function () {
            if ($(window).width() <= 1015 && $(window).width() >= 800) {
                var w = $(window).width();
                var h = w / faktor;

                $('#modul').css({
                    'width': w,
                    'height': h
                });
                $('#footer').css('width', w);
                $('#headerlinks').css('width', $(window).width() - 507);

            }

            if ($(window).width() <= 801) {

            }
        }, 50);

    });
}());
```

Comment: should be a good workaround, but does not work either for me! Don't know why.

Comment: could you provide online link to test?